# How to show prices in the format 0,00(ie for hundred 100,00)

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii,

I am using devexpress grid control.In my grid there are price tabs,in that i want the prices column to show in the format 0,00....ie if my price is 3000 then it should show 3.000,00...help me please...It is for winforms and the frontend is c#.

Comment: I assume you mean that if the price is 300 it should show 300,00?

Comment: Do you also want digit grouping?

Comment: haii fredrik,ya i want digit grouping also

Answer (score 12):

The DevExpress controls are rich and complex and there are a number of ways to do this.

The simplest is probably to set a column's display format as follows:

```
gridColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N2";
gridColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom;
```

FormatString can be any of the .NET standard or custom format strings (look in MSDN or google for "Standard numeric format strings", "Custom numeric format strings").

Answer (score 4):

If you also want to include the currency sign:

```
decimal price = 49.99M;
string data = price.ToString("c");
```

Comment: I think he wants this done inside the DevExpress grid where he has some data bound, not just formatted inside a string.

Comment: I still think this is the right approach. I have never worked with DevExpress but there should be a way to include this formatting after binding the value and before the bound value is rendered to the client, which I believe will be in string anyway. Perhaps Moo-Juice can adjust his answer so it matches DevExpress, but the way of thinking here, is correct.

Comment: @amk, Joe seems to have hit the nail on the head below.

Answer (score 4):

For a devexpress XtraGrid you can use DevExpress.Utils.FormatInfo:

```
DevExpress.Utils.FormatInfo fi = new DevExpress.Utils.FormatInfo();
fi.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
fi.FormatString = "n2";
myColumn.DisplayFormat.Assign(fi);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currency formatting depends on system settings, and sometimes it is better to specify precision explicitly:

```
double price;
string text=price.ToString("N2"); // N3 for 3 digits , etc
```