# Precision settings for Developer Express Gridview

Tags: gridview, devexpress, precision

The code for this is currently binding to a list:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "stdTable";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = "";

        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowGroup = false; //true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = false; //true;
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = false;  //true; 
    }
).Bind(Model.ListOfStuff).GetHtml()
```

The numeric values for some of my columns are showing up to 10 decimal places.  Is there a way to specify in the "settings" the precision of a specific column?

I did find this [snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895790/how-to-show-prices-in-the-format-0-00ie-for-hundred-100-00) on StackOverflow but I'm not sure how it fits here:

```
gridColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N2";
gridColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom;
```

Please assume that I cannot edit the data list before it gets to this grid control.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CustomColumnDisplayText Event

```
protected void grid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if ("columnName" == e.Column.FieldName)
    {
        e.DisplayText = performFormattingHere;
    }
}
```

You can read more about the CustomColumnDisplay Event here: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic